# Evaluating condition of if statement in awk using a second file

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to write a bash script that manipulates two files:

**file1**

```
Region  Coords. RsId    Position    Alleles Disease PValue  OddsRatio   RegionID
1p13.2  1:113839149..114551845  rs2476601   114377568   G>A Alopecia Areata 8.90E-08    1.34    869
2q13    2:111444884..111809030  rs3789129   111698040   A>C Alopecia Areata 1.50E-08    0.76    871
2q33.2  2:204611195..204817281  rs3096851   204763882   A>C Alopecia Areata 3.58E-08    1.32    802
2q33.2  2:204611195..204817281  rs1024161   204721752   G>A Alopecia Areata 3.55E-13    1.44    802
2q33.2  2:204611195..204817281  rs231775    204732714   A>G Alopecia Areata 2.20E-20    1.39    802
4q27    4:122982314..123605528  rs7682241   123523875   C>A Alopecia Areata 4.27E-08    1.34    803
4q27    4:122982314..123605528  rs7682481   123524026   G>C Alopecia Areata 4.80E-09    1.23    803
5q31.1  5:131783213..132135372  rs848   131996500   C>A Alopecia Areata 4.80E-09    1.27    872
```

**file2**

```
CHR_A         BP_A       SNP_A  CHR_B         BP_B       SNP_B           R2 
 2    204721752   rs1024161      2    204732714    rs231775     0.849535 
 2    204721752   rs1024161      2    204763882   rs3096851      0.68029 
 2    204732714    rs231775      2    204763882   rs3096851     0.739633 
 4    123523875   rs7682241      4    123524026   rs7682481            1
```

I want to read file1, and if column 3 (RsId) value is not present in either column 3 (SNP_A) or column 4 (SNP_B) of file2, write that row to output. I tried the following:

```
#this executable file is called filter_file.sh

#!/bin/bash
file1=$1
file2=$2
outfile=$3

while read CHR_A BP_A SNP_A CHR_B BP_B SNP_B R2; do 
cat $file2 | awk "(\$3!~/$SNP_A|$SNP_B/) {print}"
done < $file1 > $outfile
```

`./filter_file.sh file1 file2 out`

The awk statement worked when I tested it on its own but when I added it to the bash while loop it printed all of file1, including the header, four times. **What is wrong with my code for this step?**

Once this is working, if file1 column 3 (RsId) value is present in column 3 (SNP_A) or column 4 (SNP_B) of file2, I want to write the row to output that has the lowest value for file1 column 7 (PValue).

I am not sure how to start this second part of the task. From reading other awk questions I was thinking I could try an if statement set up something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$1
file2=$2
outfile=$3

while read CHR_A BP_A SNP_A CHR_B BP_B SNP_B R2; do 
cat $file2 | awk "{
if ((\$3!~/$SNP_A|$SNP_B/))
    print $0;
else
    #Statement that prints only the row with the lowest value for column 7 
}"
done < $file1 > $outfile
```

**What are some approaches I can use to do this step?**

If people can point to some tutorials that may be helpful for these types of problems, that is greatly appreciated.

The desired **outputfile** will look like this (order does not matter):

```
Region  Coords. RsId    Position    Alleles Disease PValue  OddsRatio   RegionID
1p13.2  1:113839149..114551845  rs2476601   114377568   G>A Alopecia Areata 8.90E-08    1.34    869
2q13    2:111444884..111809030  rs3789129   111698040   A>C Alopecia Areata 1.50E-08    0.76    871
2q33.2  2:204611195..204817281  rs231775    204732714   A>G Alopecia Areata 2.20E-20    1.39    802
4q27    4:122982314..123605528  rs7682481   123524026   G>C Alopecia Areata 4.80E-09    1.23    803
5q31.1  5:131783213..132135372  rs848   131996500   C>A Alopecia Areata 4.80E-09    1.27    872
```

Comment: It's not clear how the calculation of the minimum should work - it looks like lines 4 and 5 are the ones that are included for this reason. Could you explain why they have been chosen?

Comment: Lines 1,2,and 5 get included because they are not present in file 2, and lines 3 and 4 are included because they have the lowest p-value of the pairs from file 2. `rs7682481` is paired with `rs7682241` in file 2. Comparing the `PValue` column in file1 for  `rs7682481` (4.80E-09) and  `rs7682241`  (4.27E-08),  `rs7682481` has the lower `PValue` so it gets printed. `rs231775` is paired with both `rs1024161` and `rs3096851`, and has a lower `PValue` than either of these rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to loop through the file using bash, you can do the whole thing in awk:

```
$ awk 'NR == FNR && NR > 1 {snp_a[$3]; snp_b[$6]; next}
       FNR > 1 && !($3 in snp_a || $3 in snp_b)' file2 file1
1p13.2  1:113839149..114551845  rs2476601   114377568   G>A Alopecia Areata 8.90E-08    1.34    869
2q13    2:111444884..111809030  rs3789129   111698040   A>C Alopecia Areata 1.50E-08    0.76    871
5q31.1  5:131783213..132135372  rs848   131996500   C>A Alopecia Areata 4.80E-09    1.27    872
```

The first block applies to the first file (`file2`) and sets keys in the arrays corresponding to the two columns of interest. `next` skips any further commands, so the remainder of the script applies only to the second file (`file1`). Lines are printed when the condition is true, i.e. the line number in the file (`FNR`) is greater than 1 and the key cannot be found in either of the two arrays.

---

For the second part of your problem, things get a little bit more complicated...hopefully the comments explain things:

```
$ cat script.awk
# first file, save individual columns and pairs
NR == FNR && NR > 1 {snp_a[$3]; snp_b[$6]; pair[$3,$6]; next}

# second file, print first line
NR != FNR && FNR == 1

# second file, rest of lines
FNR > 1 {
    # print lines which aren't in either array
    if (!($3 in snp_a || $3 in snp_b)) {print}
    # save other lines and corresponding p-value
    else {s[$3] = $0; p[$3] = $8}
}
END {
    # loop through all lines
    for (i in s) {
        # empty the array f
        split("", f)
        # set initial line and min
        line = s[i]
        min = p[i]

        # locate associated lines
        if (i in snp_a) {
            for (j in snp_b) {
                # SUBSEP is a special variable used when combining keys
                # as in first block pair[$3,$6]
                if (i SUBSEP j in pair && j in s && p[j] < min) {
                    min = p[j]
                    line = s[j]
                }
            }
        }
        else if (i in snp_b) {
            for (j in snp_a) {
                if (j SUBSEP i in pair && j in s && p[j] < min) {
                    min = p[j]
                    line = s[j]
                }
            }
        }
        out[line]
    }
    for (i in out) print i
}
$ awk -f script.awk file2 file1
Region  Coords. RsId    Position    Alleles Disease PValue  OddsRatio   RegionID
1p13.2  1:113839149..114551845  rs2476601   114377568   G>A Alopecia Areata 8.90E-08    1.34    869
2q13    2:111444884..111809030  rs3789129   111698040   A>C Alopecia Areata 1.50E-08    0.76    871
5q31.1  5:131783213..132135372  rs848   131996500   C>A Alopecia Areata 4.80E-09    1.27    872
2q33.2  2:204611195..204817281  rs231775    204732714   A>G Alopecia Areata 2.20E-20    1.39    802
4q27    4:122982314..123605528  rs7682481   123524026   G>C Alopecia Areata 4.80E-09    1.23    803
```

I'm pretty certain that the logic in the `END` block can be simplified but I couldn't think of a better way to determine the "pairs". Either way, it achieves your desired output.

Comment: Looking better than my attempt. At least it is better to read since you don't need to `for` loop like me

Comment: Nvm read the question wrong.I wrote an answer but it's pretty much the same as yours so I'll just post here `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$3]=a[$6]=1;next}!a[$3]&&NR>1'`

Comment: @User112638726 Post it! It is damn good! Even compared to Tom's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` for that:

```
awk 'NR==FNR&&NR>1{r[NR]=$3$6;next}{p=1;for(i in r){if(r[i]~$3){p=0;break}}}p' \
  file2 file1
```

It is simpler to understand in a multiline version including comments:

```
# NR (row number) and FNR (current input file's row number) are equal
# only as long as we are processing the first input file.
# Means the following block only runs on file2 which is getting passed first.
# NR > 1 makes sure that we skip the header line.
NR==FNR && NR>1 {
    # Push $3 concatenated with $6 to an array call r (rows)
    r[NR]=$3$6
    # Stop processing this line and use the next. This makes sure
    # that the following block will only operate on file1
    next
}

# The following block runs on every line of file1
{
    # Init p flag
    p=1 
    # Iterate to the previously stored values
    for(i in r) {
        # If the entry of r is not matching field 3
        # Print the current line.
        if(r[i]~$3){
            # If a line matches we reset the p flag
            # and break the loop
            p=0
            break
        }
    }   
}

# Print if p flag isset (print is the default action in awk)
p
```

Output:

```
CHR_A         BP_A       SNP_A  CHR_B         BP_B       SNP_B           R2 
Region  Coords. RsId    Position    Alleles Disease PValue  OddsRatio   RegionID
1p13.2  1:113839149..114551845  rs2476601   114377568   G>A Alopecia Areata 8.90E-08    1.34    869
2q13    2:111444884..111809030  rs3789129   111698040   A>C Alopecia Areata 1.50E-08    0.76    871
5q31.1  5:131783213..132135372  rs848   131996500   C>A Alopecia Areata 4.80E-09    1.27    872
```

Comment: This gave the desired output for the first step, and thanks a LOT for annotating your code so I can understand what is going on.

Comment: @user3745089 You are welcome! There was an error in the first version of this answer. I've fixed it

Comment: Had not checked the output properly before. Curiously after the fix, this is not giving me any output lines.

Comment: It was a typo. Fixed it.